# Downloading content from txt file to a variable

Tags: vbscript

I made a counter that works when you press the button as the action in VBScript.

my code:

```
  Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1

    Dim Stuff, myFSO, WriteStuff, dateStamp

    Stuff = "Whatever you want written"

    Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set WriteStuff = myFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt", 2, True)
    WriteStuff.WriteLine(Licznik_ID)
    WriteStuff.Close
    SET WriteStuff = NOTHING
    SET myFSO = NOTHING
```

the counter variable named "Licznik_ID"
indicated by the arrow.

[image]

It is written to the file "c:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt"
And it works well.
For each time the number increases by one and is replaced and stored in the txt file.

The file contains the number 1 and the increase in the txt file appears the number 2 and so on ...

How now download the data stored with the file "c: \tmp\yourtextfile.txt" back to the variable to use it in such a way that when you start NiceForm or button has been loaded with the contents of txt file into a variable?

Comment: Does `yourtextfile.txt` just contain a number that you want incremented by one each time?

Comment: That's right. The file contains the number 1 and the increase in the txt file appears the number 2 and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Licznik_ID = myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt").ReadAll
Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1
myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt",2,True).Write(Licznik_ID)
```

FSO is kinda weird the way it does its file modes sometimes.

edit: If you want to allow this to create the file without errors if it doesn't exist, replace line 2 with this:

```
If myFSO.FileExists("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt") Then 
    Licznik_ID = myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt").ReadAll
End If
```

If the file doesn't exist, `Licznik_ID` will be `Empty`. `Empty + 1 = 1` in vbscript.

Comment: What's weird about it?

Comment: Well, mainly in that opening it `ForWriting` (2) will create a new file every time *and* make it so you can't read from it.

Comment: It's a memory stream when would you expect it to behave any differently? Also `ForWriting` doesn't force creation of a new file everytime you can control that with `create` boolean argument `object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])`.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't make sense or can't be understood, just that it can be confusing for beginners.

Comment: Ok, it's just a bit of a generalisation. Most task in programming can be confusing for beginners, but I take the point.