# AUTO INCREMENT a Field in MSSQL - Whether the required conversion is a conversion from int to string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

I made two databases MSSQL 2005 Express one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtCVo.png)

in this first data can be updated using the following VBSript:

```
Dim conn, SQL, rs
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Baza_NC;user id ='user_baza_nc';password='password'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = 'Hello'"
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "'"

myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
rem SQL = "SELECT * FROM Quality.ComplaintLog WHERE PK_ComplaintID = '" & NL_ComplaintID & "'"


rem SQL = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = " & Klienci_NC.Klient & " WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & Klienci_NC.ID & "'"

myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
```

I wanted to simplify the addition of a next number when you add the next record and I created a second database:

creating tables and auto-incrementing:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVNbo.png)

Unfortunately, now update data using VBScript:

```
Dim conn, SQL, rs
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=DJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Baza;user id ='user1';password='Pass'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = 'Hello'"
rem myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "'"

'myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci SET Klienci.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci.ID '"


myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci SET Klienci.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
rem SQL = "SELECT * FROM Quality.ComplaintLog WHERE PK_ComplaintID = '" & NL_ComplaintID & "'"


rem SQL = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = " & Klienci_NC.Klient & " WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & Klienci_NC.ID & "'"

myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
```

unfortunately, it does not work.

Action on the help button is pressed for VBScript is identical:

1 code:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci_NC SET Klienci_NC.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci_NC.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"
```

2 code:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Klienci SET Klienci.Klient = '" & Klient_niceform & "' WHERE Klienci.ID = '" & ID_zmienna & "'"
```

only the database name and the column has changed.

I did the post counter:
[Downloading content from txt file to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053477/downloading-content-from-txt-file-to-a-variable/37054414#37054414)

the help of a txt file and it works well.

Do you require character conversion of the ID column to have been transferred to the variable Licznik_ID?

How do you turn to for help of VBScript?

Comment: What is the actual question here? Also, you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. What you have here is a recipe for sql injection.

Comment: I corrected the text in the upper questions.
is it enough?

Comment: No. this just doesn't make any sense. You state things like "doesn't work". Well we don't know what that means. I have read this several times and I still don't know what the actual issue is you are trying to resolve. There appears to be something not working but as posted it is impossible to tell what it is. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ And here is another possibility. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: try `& Int(ID_zmienna) &`

Comment: The spaghetti article is good @SeanLange